# Query on hibernate entity with user-type field

Tags: hibernate, usertype

working with JPA above hibernate impl.
I map my enums by using user-type follow the good practice to store a persistence key to the enum and not the ordinal (which can be changed).

Now, i have a problem to query on the enum field. it seems that hibernate dont execute the user type convert on the name-query.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I just wrestled with this same issue, and the solution is simple: implement `LiteralType` as well as `UserType`.